# Игнорирование ненужного пакета-зависимости при обновлении

Tags: linux, archlinux, обновление, зависимости

**TL;DR** Arch Linux, pacman, два пакета конфликтуют, первый нужен, а второй является зависимостью нужного meta-пакета. Удалил второй пакет, но при обновлении pacman выдаёт ошибку, как убрать её?

---

В arch linux есть пакеты `openbabel` и `babel-cli`, которые конфликтуют. Пакет `openbabel` является зависимостью пакета `kalzium`, тот является зависимостью пакета `kde-meta-kdeedu`, который является зависимостью пакета `kde-applications-meta`. Вот схема зависимости:

```
kde-applications-meta
|
v
kde-meta-kdeedu
|
v
kalzium
|
v
openbabel
```

Пакет `kde-applications-meta` скорее всего полезный, так что его удалять нельзя. Пакет `openbabel` мне не нужен (там что-то, связанное с химией), поэтому при установки пакета `babel-cli` я удалил пакет `openbabel`, выполнив `pacman -Rdd openbabel`. Однако теперь при обновлении системы (`pacman -Syu`) pacman пытается заново установить `openbabel` (как зависимость `kalzium`), и у него, конечно, не получается:

```
разрешение зависимостей...
проверка конфликтов...
ошибка: обнаружен неразрешимый конфликт пакетов
ошибка: не удалось подготовить транзакцию (конфликтующие зависимости)
:: 'babel-cli' и 'openbabel' конфликтуют
```

Какой наиболее правильный способ сказать pacman'у, чтобы он при обновлении `kalzium` не пытался установить `openbabel`?

---

В комментариях советуют добавить пакет `openbabel` к игнорируем с помощью строки `IgnorePkg` в файле `/etc/pacman.conf`. Совет хороший, но тогда каждый раз при обновлении pacman будет спрашивать, примерно так:

```
разрешение зависимостей...
предупреждение: пропуск пакета openbabel-2.4.1-4
предупреждение: не удалось разрешить "openbabel", зависимость "kalzium"
:: Этот пакет не может быть обновлен из-за неразрешимых зависимостей:
      kalzium

:: Вы уверены что хотите пропустить этот пакет при обновлении? [y/N]
```

Как тогда убрать этот вопрос?

Comment: Странно, ни один из данных пакетов у меня не входит в `kde-app` и также `openbabel` не является зависимым от `kalzium`.
Можно игнорировать пакет `openbabel` путем добавления в конфиг.файл пакмана, раскомментировав строку `IgnorePkg` в `/etc/pacman.conf`.

Comment: Да, я так и сделал (добавил `openbabel` к строке `IgnorePkg`), но теперь pacman при каждом обновлении говорит, что `kalzium не может быть обновлен из-за неразрешимых зависимостей` и спрашивает `Вы уверены что хотите пропустить этот пакет при обновлении?`. Не знаете, как убрать этот вопрос?

Comment: @matz, насчёт того, что `openbabel` не является зависимым от `kalzium`: странно, на [странице](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/kalzium/) пакета `kalzium`пакет `openbabel` присутствует в списке зависимостей.

Comment: да, ошибся, является зависимым. Поэтому не обойтись установкой пакета `kalzium` без `openbabel`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Создай виртуальный пакет openbabel-fake, который будет предоставлять альтернативу openbabel.</s> Не прокатило из-за явного конфликта. Когда-нибудь мейнтейнеры должны с этим разобраться.

А пока:

```
extra/kalzium 17.08.1-1 (kde-applications kdeedu)
    Periodic Table of Elements
```

Кажется не очень нужным пакетом. Заменим его, тогда мета не будет ругаться.

Создай виртуальный пакет kalzium-fake, который будет предоставлять альтернативу kalzium

Пример aur/akonadi-fake. Если только один раз поставить, то можно прямо на месте исправить PKGBUILD.

Создавай свой пакет если ставить не один раз.
А полный текст пакета будет такой:

```
# Maintainer: Your Name

pkgname=kalzium-fake
pkgver=1000.0.0
pkgrel=3
pkgdesc="A fake empty kalzium package for those who don't want openbabel installed on their system"
arch=('any')
url="https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/${pkgname}/"
license=('GPL')

provides=('kalzium')
replaces=('kalzium')

package()
{
  true
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Собрал пакет, но при его установке (`pacman -Udd openbabel-fake-1000.0.0-3-any.pkg.tar`) выдаёт ошибку `openbabel-fake и babel-cli конфликтуют`. Пробовал удалить `babel-cli` и ставить пакеты `babel-cli` и `openbabel-fake` в разном порядке (с опцией `-dd`), всё равно получаю эту ошибку. Не знаешь, как исправить?

Comment: [Загрузил](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/openbabel-fake) пакет в aur, пробую устанавливать оттуда (`yaourt -Sdd openbabel-fake`), но всё равно получаю ошибку `'openbabel-fake' и 'babel-cli' конфликтуют`

Comment: в аур не надо. достаточно makepkg и pacman -U. конфликт сейчас посмотрю,.. сек

Comment: https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/babel-cli

вот тут конфликт стоит..

Comment: @diraria а попробуй выкинуть kalzium - он ведь не нужен)

Comment: Ну и будет то же самое, только не для пары `kalzium -> openbabel`, а для пары `kde-meta-kdeedu -> kalzium`?

Comment: не будет, у тебя ж нет конфликта на казюлину. встанет норм. кеды ставить не хочется, чтоб проверить. попробуй. займет это пару минут

Comment: Да, должно работать, сейчас попробую